# Must a deleted constructor be private?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, standards, access-rights

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

private:
    A(const A&) = delete;
};
```

Are these two definitions always identical to each other in any cases?

Comment: I make my deleted functions public, because it is **an announcement** to the public users that it cannot be default constructed (in your case).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

They are different **only wrt the produced diagnostics**. If you make it `private`, an additional and superfluous access violation is reported:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
private:
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A a2=a;
}
```

results in the following *additional* output from GCC 4.8:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:5: error: 'A::A(const A&)' is private
     A(const A&) = delete;
     ^
main.cpp:12:10: error: within this context
     A a2=a;
          ^
```

hence my recommendation to always make deleted methods `public`.

Comment: +1. I make my deleted functions public, because it is **an announcement** to the public users that it cannot be default constructed (in OP's case).

Comment: @Nawaz Right, it can therefore also be considered part of the class' interface/documentation.

Answer (score 14):

I want to extend [Daniel Frey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931133/must-a-deleted-constructor-be-private/18931192#18931192). Instead of making deleted methods **always** `public`, I would rather give these methods the access modifier you would (*hypothetically*) give these methods if they would not be deleted. (I do not like **always** in case a programmer has an option. If it would indeed be carved in stone to make deleted methods `public`, it should be enforced by the language itself.)

Some rules of thumb/guidelines:

- Copy and move assignment operators will be `public` in concrete and abstract classes *for most cases*.
- Copy and move constructors will be `public` in concrete classes *for most cases*.
- Copy and move constructors will be `protected` in abstract classes *for most cases*.
- Copy and move constructors will be `private` in concrete `final` classes that can only be instantiated by `friends` *for most cases*.

In all cases, you make an announcement to the appropriate users of a class instead of all users of a class.