# Does the accessibility of deleted constructors/operators matter?

Tags: c++, c++11

If a type has its default member(s)s deleted, does it make a difference what the accessibility of the declaration is?

```
class FooA {
public:
  FooA() = delete;
  FooA(FooA const&) = delete;
  FooA& operator=(FooA const&) = delete;
}

class FooB {
private:
  FooB() = delete;
  FooB(FooB const&) = delete;
  FooB& operator=(FooB const&) = delete;
}

class FooC {
protected:
  FooC() = delete;
  FooC(FooC const&) = delete;
  FooC& operator=(FooC const&) = delete;
}
```

Comment: visibility != accessibility. I changed your text to be as intended.

Comment: It does make a difference wrt the produced diagnostic. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18931192/2073257).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though [accessibility and deletedness are orthogonal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20816117/560648), it's hard to see how there could be a practical difference in the case you propose.

Answer (score 2):

Might be artificial, but it does make a little difference

```
class FooA {
private:
  FooA& operator=(FooA const&) = delete;
};

class FooB : FooA {
  // ill-formed because FooB has no access
  using FooA::operator=;  
};
```

Whether it's a *practical* difference... I don't really know. If `FooA` is a template parameter and you say `using T::BazBang`, it might happen in practice.