# delete constructor in C++: private/protected/public?

Tags: c++11, c++17, c++14

what is the best practice to delete constructor in C++: put it in private/protected/public ?:

approach 1:

```
class Foo{
public:
Foo() = delete;
}
```

approach 2:

```
class Foo{
protected:
Foo() = delete;
}
```

approach 3:

```
class Foo{
private:
Foo() = delete;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`delete` in a function declaration was introduced in C++11, [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions). Its purpose was to disable a function and indicate it is not defined and/or not to be used.

Before `delete` (i.e. C++11), the same was accomplished by making the function private. Of course, if it was supposed to be usable by the derived classes, `protected` would do too. But the examples I know did not want such function to be used anywhere and would declare it as private.

My answer is an opinion, but I would not mix the two styles. I would use either `delete` or make the function private (or protected) - but not both like in some of your examples. So my preference would be Approach 1.

I would also use `delete` instead of the trick with private, unless you need your code to run on old compilers with older standards. `delete` is self-explanatory and clean to the user.

Comment: thanks, i know a little about this history. I'm working on a project whose code contains only private deleted constructors. certainly there is a raison for that

Comment: For sure. Maybe the authors wanted to make it even more clear. Maybe for future refactorings, to make it clear that these deleted constructors ought to stay deleted. I would still stick to either one or the other, with a preference for `delete` if possible.

Comment: or if code must hope forth and back between standards,  a macro approach can be used, like Google's `GOOGLE_DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS`macro.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

duplication from  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931133/must-a-deleted-constructor-be-private): selected answer recommande to put deleted constructor on public access, but this is not compliant with the static code analysis tool: polyspace